# Redirect to a respective page from search-result in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Appreciate your kind help.

**I'm stuck need help!!**

My motive is to achieved is that:
If I search for Iphone-X then I shall redirect to mobile-phone page. Similarly, if I search LED then I redirect to TV page and so on.
**here are some code sample**
#----------------From the context.js

```
    handleSearch = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        })
    }
```

#----------------From the Top.js

```
class Top extends React.Component {    
    render() {
        return (
            <ProductConsumer>
                {
                    value => {
                        const { products,handleSearch ,search} = value;
                        const searching = products.filter(items => items.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLocaleLowerCase()));
                        return (
                            <div className='container-fluid top'>
                                <div className='row'>
                                    <div className='col-md-4 col-lg-4 mx-auto'>
                                        <InputGroup
                                            placeholder=' Find Cars, Phones and more.. '
                                            aria_label='cars'
                                            onChange={handleSearch}
                                            name='search'
                                            value={search}
                                        />
                                        {
                                            searching.map((val, index) => {
                                                {
                                                    return search === '' ? null : <div id='outer_search'>
                                                        <ul style={{ backgroundColor: "rgb(79, 141, 233)", padding: '0 5px' }}>
                                                            <li className='shadow p-2 mb-0 bg-white rounded'
                                                                key={index} >{val.title}
                                                            </li>
                                                        </ul>
                                                    </div>
                                                }

                                            })
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        )
                    }
                }
            </ProductConsumer>

        )
    }
}
```

#----------------Products Object

```
const Data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        imgsrc: image0,
        title: "Samsung A50",
        price: 35500,
        seller_desc: 'Bilal',
        description: "Lorem 1, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing?",
        location: 'karachi',
        slug: 'mobile-phones/samsung-a50',
        featured: true,
        category: {type:'mobile-phones'}
    },
];
```

[The Output Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6liKf.jpg)

Comment: Have you added routes in your app? and can you also show me your products object?

Comment: @HumayunAhmed
Yes I've added a routes..and you can check products obj on the above code, I've updated.

Comment: @Amir Ali If you have added routes correctly then just add this Link Component inside the li Tag:
`<Link to={val.category.type}>{val.title}</Link>`

Comment: thankyou brother....It's working for me